# How to group data in Angular template?

Tags: angular

I have an array with objects:

```
let arr = [{type: 1}, {type: 2}, {type: 1}, {type: 1}, {type: 3} {type: 1}];
```

I need to display this data by group `type`:

**Type 1**

```
{type: 1}
{type: 1}
{type: 1}
{type: 1}
```

**Type 2**

```
{type: 2}
```

**Type 3**

```
{type: 3}
```

Is there something in Angular template directives to do that, or anyway I should prepare data and group by `type` in component before  sending to template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zygimantas mentioned, you should do it in your component. A use-case would be:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   arrType1: any[];
   arrType2: any[];
   arr = [{type: 1}, {type: 2}, {type: 1}, {type: 1}, {type: 3} {type: 1}];
   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit() {
      // group them here and assign to arrType1 and arrType2
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can consider using a [Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) directive if you really want to have it done in your template. Couple your Pipe directive with a ngFor loop.

Comment: Adding a link to implementation of grouping in a pipe. I havent tested that code myself, it's just the first result which looks fine: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/ZfEBr1

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in your component (or in pipe, or service). Try to keep the template logic-free.

Comment: In which layer to to that? Use cases? Entity, controller or UI?

Comment: I am not sure about component, because what if I want to replace framework tomorrow? This logic will be lost

Comment: It depends. If it's one-time operation, specific to this view, do it in component. If it's related to model and it will be used in other components, create a service or a pipe. Probably I would not do it in a model, because models in frontend app usually are just data containers.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this in pipe?

Comment: Also, you could use service for such cases, group data there, and pass it to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Create pipe as below.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
 @Pipe({name: 'typeCheck'})
export class FetchTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any,key:any, type: number): any {
    return data.map(obj=>obj[key] == type);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use it in template and .ts both places.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to filter and show what you want in UI or you can use Pipe of Angular to filter it https://angular.io/guide/pipes.
Or just simply as the code below:

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of array">
    <div *ngIf="item.type === 1">
        // show anything by type
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="item.type === 2">
        // show anything by type
    </div>
    
    <div *ngIf="item.type === 3">
        // show anything by type
    </div>
</ng-container>
```